# My left position is for some reason not positioning right

Tags: javascript, css, animation, html, css-position

I have made a background with two images inside two divs next to each other that move across the screen using javascript. I made it originally to work with the divs being 2000px wide and thus the second div positioned 2000px left. I have now made an @media feature so it works with screen sizes.

The stylesheet is loading the @media properly, I have tested it by applying borders to it to show it works on the screen size. The Javascript is working, I have tested that. But the left position of it in the css doesn't change where the second div starts and there is always a gap.

This is part of the css:

```
@media (min-device-width: 800px) and (max-device-width: 1099px) {
#rotsky {position: fixed; bottom: 0px; width: 1400px; background: url('images/skybkm.jpg') no-repeat left bottom}
#rotsky2 {position: fixed; left: 1400px; bottom: 0px; width: 1400px; background: url('images/skybk2m.jpg') no-repeat left bottom}
}
#rotsky {left: 0px; height: 100%; z-index: -2}
#rotsky2 {height: 100%; z-index: -2}
```

and this is the JS

```
function applywidth() {
    var screenwidth = getWidth();
    if (screenwidth <= "799") {
        skywidth = "1000";
    } else if (screenwidth >= "800" && screenwidth <= "1099") {
        skywidth = "1400";
    } else if (screenwidth >= "1100") {
        skywidth = "2000";
    }
}
function rotate() {
    newleft-=1.1;
    nawleft-=1.1;

    if (nawleft <= (0-skywidth)) {
        nawleft = skywidth;
    }
    if (newleft <= (0-skywidth)) {
        newleft = skywidth;
    }
    var nowleft = newleft + "px";
    var nuwleft = nawleft + "px";
    document.getElementById('rotsky').style.left=nowleft;
    document.getElementById('rotsky2').style.left=nuwleft;
}
```

The rest can be seen on

http://jsfiddle.net/UkxLL

Comment: Can you post your html? Preferably in a fiddle link?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UkxLL/

Comment: how about a fiddle that actually demonstrates the problem? your fiddle shows blank

Comment: By inspecting your fiddle's HTML I see that the left position of each div is changing indefinitely.

Comment: the whole point is they're moving, but they need to start in the right place.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a rather great solution. Instead of moving the div I am moving the image within it as a background position. I have now set the left to never move and it is awesome.x

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the positioning I changed everything to:

```
position: absolute;
```

and added a few other twinks. Take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UkxLL/12/). Is this what you wanted?

PS: Next time make sure your jsfiddle works... I had to add height to the divs because the fiddle had it set to 0px thus not displaying anything.

EDIT: I changed the styles on the 2nd image to this:

```
#rotsky2 {
    margin-left: -10px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    height: 1000px; 
    z-index: -5; 
    left: 0;
}
```

Check out the jsfiddle again and if it's not working tell me what browser are you using. :)

Comment: it is still displaying a gap between the skies on my computer. I had it working with fixed before I set different resolutions.x

Comment: I'll add another thing for you to check in a sec